# Measurements: Calculate start of gradient

Tags: algorithms, measurement, change-point

let's assume you have 1000 measurements (temperature in this case), all having a  similar shape. It's a temperature profile inside a production line measured by a reference block mounted with temperature sensors (see image below)

[image: temperature profile]

I need a way to calculate the point at which the reference block enters the machine which is the starting point of the longest gradient in the graph (blue circle). It really doesn't matter if the result is a few seconds of.

So my question is is there a "mathematical/statistical" way of doing this instead of just eyeballing it every time.

Thanks in advance

Jon

Comment: No time for a full answer but suggest: (a) identify "longest [positive] gradient" as longest run of positive changes in temperature, (b) you want the first point in that longest run. In R I'd be looking at something based on `rle(sign(diff(Temp)))`.